# Background image has transition time but position transition does not

Tags: html, css

So I am looking to have a div's (buttons) background image change on hover AND move 20px left and 20px up on hover. Right now when I hover the div the background image changes on a 0.7s transition like I want it to, but the position change does not have the transition time. Any help on this would be awesome

```css
    .buttons:hover{
    background: transparent;
    background-image: url('image2');
    right: 20px;
    top: -20px;
    }
    .buttons{
    position: relative;
    width:95%;
    height: 145px;
    background-image: url('image1');
    -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
       -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
        -ms-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
         -o-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
            transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
    }
    .buttons h3{
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    }
    .buttoncontainer{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    }
    .buttoncontainer a{
    text-decoration: none;
    }
```

```html
<div class="buttoncontainer">
 <a href="#">
  <div class="buttons">
   <h3 style="font-family: helvetica;color:#13506D;">General IP Services <img src="arrow.png" alt="">
   </h3>
  </div>
 </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the animation to work, it needs to transition **from** something, **to** your new location. Define `top: 0;` and `right: 0;` before the transition.

```css
.buttons:hover{
background: transparent;
background-image: url('image2');
right: 20px;
top: -20px;
}
.buttons{
position: relative;
width:95%;
height: 145px;
right: 0;        /* Define right */
top: 0;          /* Define top */
background-image: url('image1');
-webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
   -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
     -o-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
        transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
}
.buttons h3{
position: relative;
top: 50px;
}
.buttoncontainer{
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}
.buttoncontainer a{
text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttoncontainer">
<a href="#">
    <div class="buttons">
        <h3 style="font-family: helvetica;color:#13506D;">General IP Services <img src="arrow.png" alt="">
        </h3>
    </div>
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! awesome and easy fix!